# Error - /bin/sh: java: command not found

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext2

I get the following error when I try to run JSLint from SublimeText 2 on my Mac:

```
/bin/sh: java: command not found
```

I think it is to do with Java not being in the `PATH` on Mac, can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 5):

Open up terminal and start editing .bash_profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

then add the following

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk<your JDK folder>

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk<your JDK folder>/bin
```

Save and close.

Comment: @beny23 don't have my Mac to check atm

Answer (score 4):

From [this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/) and a couple of others, it looks like you edit your `~/.profile` file (the `.profile` in your home directory), find the line that starts with `export PATH=...`, and add the Java `bin` directory at the beginning or end, separating it from the previous/next element with a colon (`:`).

E.g., if it looks like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

change it to

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:/path/to/java/bin
```

or

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/path/to/java/bin:$PATH
```